# SharePoint as a content manager and business process automation engine

Tags: .net, sharepoint

We are considering to re-implement or change our product (implemented in C#) to use SharePoint as a content manager and business process automation engine at the backend. This software mainly handles all the mailings, manages organization's various business specific worklfows and documents, and all these are connected (ie. from a mail a new workflow can be created etc.) in the organization hierarchy. We are using IBM content manager and IBM websphere process server at the moment. If decided, we are  planning to make it happen this or next year, hence will be able to use sharepoint 2010. What are pros and cons of such a change? Do you have such experience? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience in IBM Content Manager and Websphere Process Server. But SharePoint does provide a powerful content management feature and workflow system. For most business scenarios, you can use out-of-the-box SharePoint features and workflows. Power users can design their own content types within SharePoint UI, and can even create custom workflows with SharePoint designer.

If you really need to extend SharePoint by writing custom codes, it should be quite since you already use C#. There are some Visual Studio extensions to help you create new SharePoint features. You can leverage Windows Workflow Foundation also to build custom and complicated workflows.

If your company uses Microsoft Office product, then it will be even better. SharePoint can work seamlessly with products such as Outlook, Word, or Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an experience of websphere process server and IBM content Manager but i've used the Sharepoint which is a powerful content management system. In Sharepoint you can use some out of the box features which can be unlocked by getting the premium package. Also, it helps you with the office automation system.

Though, sharepoint has some limited options like while the task is pending it'll not ping you about that task telling you that it is pending. Whereas, in **Laserfiche** you can get lots of other  new options like in the case of pending task, after the due date it shall generate an email for the concerning officer (Image Attached)

[image]

If you are going to change or shift from IBM content manager to Sharepoint, I suggest you to give Laserfiche  Enterprise Content Management system a try. You don't have to go buy it at once, rather check it by using the 30 days free trial with full features. You can easily get a quote from them